# How does the Software Center keep track of packages?

Tags: package-management

How does the Software Center keep track of installed packages? In which files/database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dpkg` (Software-Center is a graphical front-end of dpkg) keeps track of the installed packages in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`.

Comment: This seems like the right answer - Software Center gets its information about which packages are installed from dpkg's database.

Comment: Sounds right but when you want to install a package, you also need to find the associated .deb file to know which files to remove right? Where are those .deb files cached?

Comment: That didn't make sense.  You remove files when you UNinstall a package.  That information is in /var/lib/dpkg/info/.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, it uses [xapian](http://xapian.org/) databases located at `/var/cache/software-center/xapian`.

From a quick read over the code [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~software-store-developers/software-center/trunk/view/head:/softwarecenter/db/update.py), specifically the 'rebuild_database' function, it looks like the above are built/re-built from the apt cache (using the [Python-apt](https://launchpad.net/python-apt) wrapper, which in turn uses libapt-pkg).